# Can't add code samples from mobile version

Tags: support, code-formatting, mobile-web

Is it possible to add a question with big samples of code from the mobile version of the site?

Yes, I know that it's very convenient to use the mobile app, but in some situations it can be better to stick to site, not the app. Or maybe I didn't find the "add code" button on mobile, didn't I?